# htacess code not working and shows the full url with parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make my urls user friendly, when I am clicking on a link I am getting this url now domain.com/?category=about&page=about, what I need is to show the url 
domain.com/about only to the visitor.

I have written the code , but it is not working .

This is the ht access code

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(about|eshop|ecommerce|design|faq|contact)/$ index.php?category=$1&page=$1
RewriteRule ^index(\.php)? http://mywebi.co.il/ [R=301,C]
```

Kindly check the web site [here](http://mywebi.co.il)

Please help me ,

Regards,
Sushmitha Malhotra

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

# external redirection to get /about in browser
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

# internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^(about|eshop|ecommerce|design|faq|contact)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have tried the code , but it is not working , please check the url http://mywebi.co.il/

Comment: Ok but what should I check on that site?

Comment: Do you have only these rules or you have other rules too in your .htaccess?

Comment: Yes U have only these rules in my htaccess

Comment: OK post your current htaccess in question.

Comment: I have already posted it in question , kindly check it please

Comment: That is your original .htaccess but didn't you incorporate my suggested code above?

Comment: Yes I have tried before , it was not working , let me again clear the old codes and update your codes .